# What is being requested or sent in this XMLHTTPRequest handleSubmit for forms?

Tags: javascript, servlets, react-native, xmlhttprequest

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
        if (request.readyState !== 4) {
            return;
        }

        if (request.status === 200) {
            console.log('success', request.responseText);
        } else {
            console.warn('error');
        }
    };

    request.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/index.jsp');
    request.send();

    event.preventDefault();
}
```

This is the boilerplate XMLHttpRequest available on react-native and this handleSubmit is supposed to handle a login form, but I'm not exactly sure what is being posted if anything. From what I know, I'm supposed to send a JSON object with the login information and then the servlet will handle the incoming data, but I'm not really sure what is happening in this process.

Comment: It's just posting nothing to your `request.open` URL then getting a String as your `request.responseText` from that same URL.

Comment: I see, and I'm seeing that I can't access the back-end server because of some access point origin error, which I assume is because I'm trying to access a different domain and is being blocked for security purposes. Do I need to set up my front end as a proxy server or something like that?

Comment: You have to have CORS access, otherwise you can't access it.

Comment: Yes I figured it out by creating a CORSFilter class, thanks!